# sheaves on thickened nodal cubics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, sheaf-theory

Suppose F is an algebraically closed field (of any characteristic) and that h in F[x,y,z]
is an irreducible cubic form defining a plane curve C with a node. A lot is known about
sheaves on C; for example Drozd and Greuel classified indecomposable torsion free sheaves
in terms of combinatorial data. I'd like to know if there's anything comparable when h
is replaced by a power of h.

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to MO! 

Comment: @paul Monsky: I think I can classify _rank 1_, torsion-free sheaves on the curve defined by h^2=0. Is this the sort you are after?  If so, I can try to write something up.

Comment: Apologies--I didn't see your comment until now. I'm hoping, doubtless in vain, for something in arbitrary rank. (I recently used the Drozd-Greuel classification in calculating the dimension of the quotient
of F[x,y,z], char F=p, by the ideal generated by h and the q th powers
of some fixed homogeneous elements, where q=1,p,p^2,p^3,... There's a
very simple formula for all these dimensions, and the computer suggests that something similar is happening when h is replaced by a
power of h). But any info you can give is welcome. You can send
me mail at Brandeis University.
